# Excel: How can I replace a short string of characters with one character?

Tags: microsoft-excel, characters, string

So, I keep a spreadsheet of all of my bowling scores and how I do on each frame. To show that I got a split, I use "#s", where # is how many pins I knocked over, but I want to replace all of these with characters like ②, which would have the respective # in the circle. I have tons of scores in my spreadsheet, so changing everything by hand would take ages. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that you are using Excel 2007 or newer.

You can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-H to perform a find-and-replace (hold Control (Ctrl) on the keyboard, and press H at the same time).  In the "Find what:" box enter your #s (such as 2s) and in the "Replace with box:" paste in your circled # (②).  Click the Replace All button.

[image: Find Replace before replace]
[image: Find Replace after replace]

Note, you will have to do this per #.  For each #, you must already have the circled character.  You will have to repeat this exercise per sheet in the workbook.

Comment: Ha, I can't believe I didn't think of the simple find and replace. Thanks!

Comment: Also, would there be a way to have it replace text as it comes up? Say, I type in "7s" and it immediately switches it out for the circled 7.

Comment: I don't think this feature is as advanced as that.  But, there are dropdowns to select previously entered values: if you had already typed in "circled 7", "circled 6", and "circled 5", you could click the dropdown and select whichever you want from there.